# Guardar datos leidos de una BD de forma permanente para no tener que volver a leerlos

Tags: php

me gustaría si es posible que alguien pudiera darme algunas pautas para realizar el siguiente comportamiento, en PHP 7, espero explicarme bien.

Inicio la aplicación leyendo datos de un usuario desde  BD (id, nombre, email, etc.).

Almaceno los datos en una clase que tiene propiedades y métodos estáticos, según tengo entendido de esa forma no se borra el contenido.

Marco una variable booleana a true de manera que indico que los datos de usuario ya se han leído, para que al refrescar el navegador no me los vuelva a leer de la BD, si no que los recoja de las propiedades estáticas de la clase.

Muestra los datos en pantalla y correcto, pero al refrescar el navegador el problema es que se pierden, las propiedades me aparecen vacías, no encuentro la forma de hacer persistentes esos datos.

Básicamente lo que quiero es que después de hacer el login y validar el usuario, poder mostrar en la pantalla principal de la aplicación el nombre y el email, la primera vez lo hace bien pero en cuanto refresco la pantalla del navegador (que digamos empezaría a ejecutarse el index.php de nuevo) pues me pasa lo que os comento.

Si alguien me puede indicar alguna web, documento o vídeo donde se explique algo de eso se lo agradecería.

un cordial saludo

Comment: El tema que buscas se llama sesiones. Busca en google Sesiones en PHP... hay muchos vídeos que te serán de ayuda.
https://diego.com.es/sesiones-en-php

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, el tema de sesiones lo conozco, pero lo que quiero es evitar guardar esos datos en una variable de sesión precisamente, para que no puedan ser interceptadas de ninguna manera. De hecho lo tenía hecho con sesiones, pero no me acaba de convencer la solución, por eso quería saber si ha alguna otra manera de hacer persistentes esos datos en memoria, para no tener que volver a leerlos de la BD. Gracias por la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Primero que todo debemos resaltar que PHP se ejecuta de principio a fin por cada request que se hace, luego de la ejecución el script muere liberando la memoria.

Si usted desea persistir datos de alguna manera para no tener que consultarlos de nuevo en la base de datos, debe usar sistema de caché, pueden ser en un archivo o en memoria, Redis, Memcache entre otros.

La lógica es la siguiente, primero debes preguntar si los datos están en caché y si es así tomarlos directamente de la caché en caso contrario consultarlos en la base de datos y almacenarlos en caché de esa manera el siguiente request no implicará una query a la base de datos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, voy a implementar lo que me comentas. Un saludo